# No equal margins on left and right, why is that

Tags: html, css

just practicing on div positioning. In the following code below, the RED and GREEN divs are inside the `.content` div. Both the left margin (to the left of red div) and right margin (to the right of green div) are set EQUALLY as 0.3%

Because of this there are two small vertical strips of dark blue lines (which actually is the color of the .content div) exposed on left and right.) However, if you note, the line widths are NOT equal. Please see the screenshot to understand this better. Why is that even after setting the equal margins on both?

[image: Screenshot]

```css
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(173,192,241,1);
    }

.wrapper {
 height: 725px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1); */
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}



.topimage {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 175px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(0,102,204,1); */
 position: absolute;
 /* [disabled]border: thin solid rgba(255,0,0,1); */
}

.topimage img{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: -9px; */
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.menu {
 background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1);
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 50px;
 max-width: 960px;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: rgba(20,35,214,1);
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
}

.leftcontent {
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 83.7%;
 top: 175px;
 /* [disabled]position: relative; */
 border-left-color: rgba(205,205,205,1);
 margin-left: 0.3%;
}

.rightcontent {
 background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 15.7%;
 /* [disabled]position: relative; */
 top: 175px;
 margin-right: 0.3%;
}

.footer {
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="topimage">

</div>
<div class="menu">
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="leftcontent">
</div>
<div class="rightcontent">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: no. I want the colors on both the divs

Comment: more space in rightside content, you have to reduce that ?

Comment: well, it seems to me that the widths of blue strips are equal but slight difference appears because of the faziness of the blue strips which is more obvious on green side.

Answer (score 2):

its taking .3% of rightcontent div
your  leftcontent div and rightcontent div not Equal for that Margin not equal

Comment: can you explain in detail?

Comment: Think your leftcontent div width 500px so 0.3% is 1.5px, and your rightcontent div width 100px so 0.3% is 0.3px now see is it equal ?

Comment: oh ok! I thought the 0.3% is of the parent div (which is the .content)?

Comment: Now you can make it equal if you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Browser may have small bug converting the decimal percentage values to actual pixels.

below changes were done and looks equal spacing on both sides. Applied the padding to `.content` with `display:table;`

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(20,35,214,1);
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
      padding: 0 .3%;
      display: table;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

.leftcontent {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 175px;
    border-left-color: rgba(205,205,205,1);
        max-width: 84%;
}

.rightcontent {
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 175px;
        max-width: 16%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/yk7kn8qw/2/

Comment: Yes, that works. Now can you explain what `*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}` does? And why display as table makes this difference?

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box; ` specifies padding and border is included in the total width. so content's 100% width includes the padding also.. I'll need to analyse about the display property ...

Comment: ok, appreciate your support. I am understanding it now. are you ok in sharing your email? just needed some advice on e-commerce websites if possible.

Comment: felixaj3@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```css
 *{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(173,192,241,1);
    }

.wrapper {
 height: 725px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1); */
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}



.topimage {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 175px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(0,102,204,1); */
 position: absolute;
 /* [disabled]border: thin solid rgba(255,0,0,1); */
}

.topimage img{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: -9px; */
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.menu {
 background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1);
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 50px;
 max-width: 960px;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: rgba(20,35,214,1);
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-right:3px;
}

.leftcontent {
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 83.7%;
 top: 175px;
 /* [disabled]position: relative; */
 border-left-color: rgba(205,205,205,1);
}

.rightcontent {
 background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 16.3%;
 /* [disabled]position: relative; */
 top: 175px;
}

.footer {
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="topimage">

</div>
<div class="menu">
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="leftcontent">
</div>
<div class="rightcontent">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: *{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

Answer (score 0):

If we remove margin from both leftcontent and rightcontent, then you can notice that already there is some space between both div, now to reduce that you can you this margin has below. Visually creating left and right same.

```
.leftcontent {
    margin-left:0.35%;
}
.rightcontent {
margin-right:0.25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of margin-left & margin-right using percent (%). You use max-width for left and right and margin-left & margin-right is calculate depending on max-width. So, it is different. You can use margin-left and margin-right with px.